# java:S1067 - Reduce the number of conditional operators (5) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3)

Tags: java, sonarqube

How can I reduce the number of conditional operators?
Sonar showing Major issue like Reduce the number of conditional operators (5) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3) but those all condition mandatory to keep in this block:

```
private String processfromOrigin(Object value) {
    if ((value instanceof A) || (value instanceof B)
            || (value instanceof C) || (value instanceof D)
            || (value instanceof E)
            || (value instanceof F)) {
        return ((baseDto) processo).getProcess();
    } else if (value instanceof G) {
        return ((G) value ).getProcess();
    } else if (value instanceof H) {
        return ((H) value ).getProcess();
    } else {            
        return (String) value ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sonar is just giving you advice. In this case you can ignore it. This could be a smell that there should be a common interface that A...F should all implement.

Comment: It's odd that you're checking `value` but then casting `processo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like below to simplify the first conditional in the if block:

```
import static java.util.Stream.of;
boolean checkABCDEF = of(A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class, E.class, F.class).
                      anyMatch(aClass -> aClass.isInstance(value))
```

of, you can encapsulate it in a local method:

```
    private boolean isABCDEF(Object x) {
        return Stream.of(A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class, E.class, F.class).
                      anyMatch(aClass -> aClass.isInstance(x));
    }
```